# How much ground up coffee will be yielded from whole bean coffee?

Tags: beans, ground-coffee

What I mean is: If I put 1/4 cup whole bean coffee in the grinder,how much ground up coffee am I going to end up with? 1/4 cup of ground coffee? A few tablespoons? I am talking about volume (cup/ tablespoons etc) not really weight.

Thanks.

18 and drinking my first cup, after I make it of course!

Comment: How fine will you grind it? Different grinds will have different volumetric measurements. Different grinds are used for different brewing methods. Do you know what brewing method you will use?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to talk about volume here. Volume is not a relevant variable in the process of making coffee and obviously the volume will be different for different grind sizes as well. That is why cups and spoons as a measurement in coffee making is completely pointless, you need to measure the weight to achieve consistently good results.

Comment: There is a very nice chapter in the book "What Einstein Told His Cook: Kitchen Science Explained" by Wolke, which explains how the shape of the measuring cup makes a difference for larger grains even if all compared measuring cups hold precisely the same volume. Now coffee beans are so large that you can't really compare the results between differently shaped measuring cups....which is why coffee beans are pretty much always measured in grams/ounces/pounds/etc.